# How to Load an Image from a URL in Windows Phone 8?

Tags: windows-phone-8, c#-3.0

I'm using this code to load a image via HTTP/URL.

```
Uri uri = new Uri("http://Abundantcode.com/image.jpg", UriKind.Absolute)
imageControl.Source = new BitmapImage(uri);
```

How to use string-variable instead of a directly parsed string.

Comment: You want to use a "data URL", as described in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
<Image Source="{Binding ImageUri}" />
```

Now set `ImageUri` to whatever `string` you want.